# Import structure that works both in packages and out, in both Python 2 and 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, python-2.x, python-import

When I developed a package purely for Python 2, I could use the plain `import b` syntax to import a relative path without caring about whether the importing file was in a package or not. This had the advantage that I could run an `if __name__ == "__main__":` block of any file simply by executing the file, and all imports would work fine.

After adding Python 3 support, I had to move to the new relative import syntax, which is also supported by 2.7: `from . import b`. However, this syntax *only* works inside packages. Directly executing the file directly no longer works:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./a.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import b
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

A workaround is to call the file by importing it as a module from an upper directory:

```
python -m foo.a
```

However, this places a requirement on the work directory, which prevents you from piping the output to some other program that also cares about the working directory.

Is there a way to have your cake and eat it too? I.e. support both running as a script and importing as part of a package, while working in both Python 2 and 3?

---

Example package structure:

```
foo/
foo/__init__.py
foo/a.py (imports b)
foo/b.py (imports c)
foo/c.py
```

I would like both of the following to work for x in (a, b, c):

```
import foo.x (in some file when foo/ is in path)

python[23] path/to/foo/x.py
```

---

The comment below mentions setting `__package__` according to [PEP 366](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/), but "if the script is moved to a different package or subpackage, the boilerplate will need to be updated manually."

**Update**: I tried to make the [PEP 366](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/) solution work, but couldn't figure it out. It says:

> Additional code that manipulates `sys.path` would be needed in order for direct execution to work without the top level package already being importable.

That's the case when executing a file from a non-imported package. What would that additional code look like?

Comment: If your package name is shadowed by a built-in module, it's hardly a usable package, is it? In any case, [setting `__package__` may help](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/).

Comment: @user2357112, a subpackage can have a name that clashes with a built-in module, yet still be perfectly usable, although I grant that's probably not a good idea. Anyway, the "other program cares about WD" is an actual problem I had. I'll take a look at `__package__`.

Comment: I am not absolutely sure if it helps, but I have covered that topic at least partly in this Python application template: https://github.com/jgehrcke/python-cmdline-bootstrap

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke, thanks, but that isn't really a solution. Having a separate runner file for each file would be a pain. Plus they'd get tangled when you install the package.

Comment: I believe `__package__` is the solution you're looking for, but I don't understand your edits about trying it.  You not only want `import foo.x` to work, but you want it to also automatically work even if you rename `foo` to something else?  If you change the package name, you obviously will have to change the imports.  In general, **imports are only meant to work with modules/packages on `sys.path`**.  If you want to fake it so you can import something that is not on `sys.path`, you will need to modify `sys.path` inside your program to have the script add its package directory to the path.

Comment: @BrenBarn, at this point I would be fine with having to change imports. However, I couldn't figure out the way to get `__package__` changes to work – i.e. what `sys.path` manipulations should be done. I'll update the question to clarify.

Comment: (What I meant by changing imports is that `import b` in `foo.b` would stop working if `foo` got renamed. It would be annoying, but not a big deal.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution based on [KronoS' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24021709/1495539) and comments that allows identical boilerplate for modules regardless of path or package names:

```
if __name__ == "__main__" and __package__ == None:
    import importlib
    import os.path
    import sys
    def _gen_path():
        head, tail = os.path.split(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        while head:
            if not os.path.isfile(os.path.join(head, '__init__.py')):
                yield head
                return
            head, tail = os.path.split(head)
            yield tail
    def _load_package():
        path = list(_gen_path())
        syspath = sys.path[:]
        sys.path[:0] = [path.pop()]
        package = '.'.join(reversed(path))
        importlib.import_module(package)
        sys.path = syspath
        return package
    __package__ = _load_package()
```

It walks the file path up as far as there are `__init__.py` files marking packages, then imports the parent package of the module, setting `__package__` correctly. After this, relative imports like `from ..bar import baz` just work.

---

Too bad putting those functions in their own module gets you back to square one. Also, there doesn't seem to be a Python 2/3 portable way to limit the effects of `sys.path` changes to just that import, so anything in the base directory may shadow an absolute import in *any* module or package that gets imported with the parent package.

Comment: Seeing your answer here, only emphasizes my original answer.  I would highly recommend using virtual environments ([virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)) and testing your code there.  This isn't very Pythonic and IMO will ultimately lead to more problems created than solved.

Comment: @KronoS, I agree that it's not very Pythonic at all, and I hesitated before posting it. In my ideal world I could just do relative imports outside packages (I mean why not?). However, virtualenv is, again, not a solution for my particular usecase of running tests before installing (possibly to virtualenv).

Comment: I'd like to take this discussion to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116/fake-programmers) sometime so as to not clog up the comments.  I must not be fully understanding your situation b/c I don't see why using virtualenv is not a viable use case.

Comment: @KronoS, basically, setup.py launches another program (with requirements on workdir) to run some tests on the modules when called to install the package.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to have your cake and eat it too? I.e. support both running as a script and importing as part of a package, while working in both Python 2 and 3?

No..... Maybe...  But from what I can gather of what you're trying to do, you're making a problem even more complicated that it should be.  I would create a package like normal where you **can** support both Python 2 & 3.  Then install using a [setup script](https://docs.python.org/3.4/distutils/setupscript.html) and import the package into the script without having to use relative paths.  This gives you the freedom of script execution anywhere, and Python 2 & 3 compatibility of your package.

---

I still hold to my original statement above in that I believe you're making this more complicated than it really needs to be OR you're not giving us all the information as to why this HAS to be done this way.  None the less, If you follow what PEP 366 states this should work.  In your modules where the script resides (i.e. contains `if __name__ == "__main__":`) then add the following lines to the beginning (or before your main `if __name__ == "__main__":`) of the file:

```
if __name__ == "__main__" and __package__ == None:
        __package__ == "expected.package.name"
        sys.path.append(<path to root package 'expected'>)
```

This of course means that you'll need to manually update these if you ever move the script around, or if the package gets moved, or anything related to that path gets moved around (hence why I still think an installation is by far the better option here).

Comment: I'm already doing that (the files are installable and usable with the module syntax), but the main use case I have is for running tests *before* installing. Even after installing, being able to treat a script both as part of a package and an executable is useful. E.g. you can expose it on the command line with a simple symbolic link: `/usr/local/bin/foo -> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bar/foo.py`. (The PEP also gives a rationale for adding the feature.)

Comment: @otus while they give a 'rationale' for the feature it isn't implemented and is going to be of more work for you to get the way you "exactly" want it right now.

Comment: What do you mean isn't implemented? [It](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/)'s Status: Final, part of Python 2.6+.

Comment: @otus what you want isn't implemented.  You can follow the guidelines of PEP 366 if you're willing to add the root of the package to `sys.path`, which in essence is the same as installing the package as I've mentioned above.

Comment: I tried adding the root of the package to `sys.path` as the PEP suggested, but couldn't get it to work, there was an ImportError. That's why I updated the question to ask what that code should look like. If it works, it is not the same as installing, because the path manipulation happens in Python whenever I run the file rather than my having to do it in the shell to fake an install.

Comment: My question is, why is this so necessary?  What's so wrong with simply installing the module?

Comment: Because I'm looking for ways to easily test the modules before installing and against an installed package. Trying to patch together the workflow that Python 3 broke, basically.

Comment: Why not use a 'virtualenv' then?  I've update the answer to match what I think you're trying to do, but I don't believe this is really your answer.

Comment: Using your code with `__package__ = "foo"` and `sys.path.append("/home/.../test/")` (in test/foo/a.py), and adding `from . import b`, I get `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package` from Python 2 and `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import` from Python 3.

Comment: try this instead: `sys.path.append("/home/.../test/foo/")`

Comment: Ok, figured it out. The `foo` module needs to be actually imported after the `sys.path` manipulation. This lead to an answer I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can add the directory where `a` and `b` modules live in the PYTHONPATH (ref: https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH).

Also, as stated in at the above link, the directory where the module `a` lives would automatically added to the PYTHONPATH, if a is the main module. Eg if you have following code in `/test/a.py` and `/test/b.py` files:

/test/a.py

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    print(sys.path)

    import b
    print('this is a')
```

/test/b.py

```
print('this is b')
```

And you execute `a` as:

```
$ cd /test/
$ python3 a.py
```

You'll get a output:

```
['', '/usr/lib/python34.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.4', '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-linux', '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages']
this is b
this is a
```

Also, if you'll execute:

```
$ python3 /test/a.py
```

You'll get output:

```
['/test', '/usr/lib/python34.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.4', '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-linux', '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages']
this is b
this is a
```

Comment: Both `a` and `b` and part of package `foo`. You've broken `import foo.a` on Python 3 by removing the dots. Also, what if `b` needs to import `c` – it's not `"__main__"` when executing `a` so how would I apply what you used?

Comment: I've added the package structure to the question so you can maybe see what I mean.

Comment: If you have a package `foo` then you should always import and execute `foo.x`. If don't have a package them import and execute `x`. As you asked, if you'll import `c` in `b` in the above example, it would work just fine as the directory where `x` (a, b, c) lives is already in the PYTHONPATH. Also, if you need you can add both directories 'foo/' and it's parent to PYTHONPATH.

Comment: "If you have a package foo then you should always import and execute foo.x." – The whole problem (see title) is to not have to do that, but to be able to directly execute the file, like `python a.py`, as well. For the rationale, see the question and the linked PEP.

Comment: In that case you may do this: "Also, if you need you can add both directories 'foo/' and it's parent to PYTHONPATH"

Comment: I don't see how that would help, at least without making all the modules in the package shadow their equivalents in other places. I.e. if the package contains module "bar", it would shadow any similarly named top level package (or be shadowed by, depending on order). Namespacing would break.